# Item id for the articles fetched by alias

Tags: itemid

I have made a module in which I am fetching articles from a keyword present in alias.

```
    $query="myquery";

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result=$db->loadAssocList();

    foreach($result as $row){

$url = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=".$row['aid'].":".$row['aalias']."&catid=".$row['cid'].":".$row['calias']."&Itemid=???";
}
```

In building URL, how I can find item id?

I have tried to get item id from the following code found at 
[Get full link from menu item field type](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/803/get-full-link-from-menu-item-field-type)

```
$itemid = $params->get('field_name'); 

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$link = $menu->getItem($itemid)->link;
```

But not sure what to pass in $params->get('field_name') in this case.

Comment: Which Joomla version are you using? I am a little bit confused about the colons ':' in your URL. 
An URL in Joomla 3.x would rather look like 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=555', for example.

Comment: I am using joomla 3.4.1. URL is working fine if I give item id manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use content component route helper. It will find `Itemid` for you.

```
<?php

include JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

$articleLink = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row['aid'], $row['cid']);

// SEF url
$articleLinkSEF = JRoute::_($articleLink);

?>
```

Comment: Luckly enough I stumbled upon this! Where on earth is documented that `ContentHelperRoute` class? I tried searching but can't find it anywhere! Only found [JHelperRoute](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHelperRoute.html) but AFAICT it's not the same thing.